# How to protect against exploitation of email addresses from an mistakenly expired domain?

Tags: email, exploit, dns-domain

I have a domain name that I have registered for a long time. Due to a combination of bad luck and oversight, the domain name expired and was rebought by somebody else. I am attempting to buy the domain name back, but I am not sure if I will be able to.

My domain is associated with a google apps account. Could the new owner of the domain in theory recreate an existing email address and intercept future emails people attempt to send to me?

For example, if my current email is x@mydomain.com, could the new domain owner create x@mydomain.com and receive future emails people try and send to me?

Comment: Connect the existing account if its possible to a new domain.  If you are worried about him getting email directed towards you, he can only recieve new email, not any existing email.  Make everyone aware of your new domain for the time being.

Comment: @Ramhound, thanks. I know he can only receive new email (that's the problem). My internal users are aware of the problem, but I obviously can't set up an auto-responder to new incoming emails...

I plan on finding a new domain if I can't get the old one back.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you don't own the domain, all of what is done with it can't be yours, including the emails.

Since the new owner possess the domain, he can manage the MX DNS of this domain (used for Email services) and do whatever he wants to do with this, including creating any accounts@mydomain.com, redirect them to whatever/whoever he wants, etc.

So he's able to create one of your old email, and use it. It's not an attack since he's the owner.

The only "timelapse" you have is the DNS propagation. But I assume that if you get back your domain, it won't be made in less than hours after the purchase.

To be clear : **He's now the owner, so he can do whatever he wants on it.**

Comment: I was afraid of that. Makes a lot of sense, thanks!

Comment: Sorry about that, but there's no solution except discussing with the new owner. Eventually negociating (at least) the redirection of your old email address to yours, even if you aren't the owner of the domain now. (Hope it's not "contact@mydomain.com" or something like that!)

Comment: I'm trying to contact him directly. I think the moral of the story is, don't let domain names expire. :)

Comment: I more than agree with that! :) Which registrar were you using?

Comment: GoDaddy. They offer a service to try and broker a deal to purchase a registered domain name, we'll see where it goes.